# Heatmap clustering with annotion name and category

Tags: bioinformatics, bioconductor

I would like to make a comparison of clustering (heatmap) with the annotation of the genes differently expressed like this  :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naK4q.png)

This picture is from an paper and they used Blast2go to do it. i wish to have free tools or r package or simple tutorials to do it. i have a list of gene as dataset obtained from Deseq2.
your ideas will be a great help to me.

Comment: Check the [ComplexHeatmap](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html) package, you can find extensive tutorials here: https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/

Comment: You may be interested in the existence of a bioinformatics-dedicated stackexchange site: bioinformatics.stackexchange.com You may also be interested in deeptools.